# How can I grep files of specific name patterns?

Tags: perl, grep, glob

I have a piece of code in Perl to grep for files with specific names under a directory.

```
push @{ $output{archives} }, grep {-f $_} "$output{dir}/result0.txt”, "$output{dir}/outcome.txt”;
say "@{ $output{archives} } \n";
```

This will search for files of names `result0.txt`, `outcome.txt` under the directory `$output{dir}`. These results will be pushed into the array `$output{archives}`.

How can I search for file names of pattern `outcome_0.txt`, `outcome_1.txt`, `outcome_2.txt`, etc. and push to the array?

I tried changing `"$output{dir}/outcome.txt”` to `"$output{dir}/outcome*.txt”`, but it is not giving any results at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want find files matching `outcome_*.txt` you can use the `glob` function or aka `<>`:

```
￼￼push @{ $output{archives} }, grep {-f $_} <"$output{dir}/outcome_*.txt">;
```

or, using `glob` instead of `<>`:

```
￼￼push @{ $output{archives} }, grep {-f $_} glob "$output{dir}/outcome_*.txt";
```

or using a more specific regexp:

```
push @{ $output{archives} }, grep {(-f $_) && /outcome_\d+\.txt$/}  glob "$output{dir}/*";
```

From [perldoc glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) :

> **glob**
>   In list context, returns a (possibly empty) list of filename
>   expansions on the value of EXPR such as the standard Unix shell
>   /bin/csh would do. In scalar context, glob iterates through such
>   filename expansions, returning undef when the list is exhausted.

See [perldoc glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) and [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) for more information.

Comment: Apologies for my Perl ignorance -- what is the significance of the two characters prepended to `push`?

Comment: @vintnes What two characters?

Comment: `￼￼push` Appears to be a Firefox issue; not replicable in Chrome

Comment: Thanks @HåkonHægland , with push @{ $output{archives} }, grep {-f $_} <"$output{dir}/result0.txt”, "$output{dir}/outcome_*.txt">; I was able to achieve it .